# How can I convert textbox value to double in c#?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and using windows forms. 
I have 2 textboxes `textbox1` and `textbox2`.

Lets say textbox1 has a value of 22, when I click on textbox2, the value in textbox1 should change to double (22.00).

```
textbox1.text = "22";
private void textBox2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // convert the value in textbox1 to double .
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private void textBox2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     // TODO: handle exceptions
     textBox1.Text = double.Parse(textBox1.Text).ToString("F2");
}
```

1) You can find the format strings here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx.

2) `double.Parse(...)` can throw an exception: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

[Double.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its double-precision
>   floating-point number equivalent.

[Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its double-precision
>   floating-point number equivalent. A return value indicates whether the
>   conversion succeeded or failed.

You should use Double.TryParse instead of Double.Parse to prevent of falling your application by exception if user entered an invalid value.

So, the code would be:

```
var sourceValue = textBox1.Text;
double doubleValue;
if (double.TryParse(sourceValue, out doubleValue)){
      // Here you already can use a valid double 'doubleValue'
} else {    
      // Here you can display an error message like 'Invalid value'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
private void textBox2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    double number = double.Parse = textbox1.Text;        
    textbox1.Text = double.Parse(Math.Round(number, 2).ToString();
}
```

where 2 is number of digits after decimal separator

Comment: You cannot use `Round` with a `string` and also `Text` has a capital `T`.

Answer (score 1):

use the `double.Parse()` function. Example:

```
double textBoxValue;
textbox1.Text = "22";
private void textBox2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
         textBoxValue = double.Parse(textbox1.Text);
    }
```

Hope this helps,

Jason.