# Don't know where these errors are coming from

Tags: c#, syntax-error

I'm new to both stackoverflow and c# so I'm not sure if this is the appropriate place to put this, however, I would like help identifying where the errors lie in this specific program. This program is a form that takes user input for four grades, converts them to double, and outputs the average as both a number and letter grade.

In terms of what's wrong, I'm getting errors on the "TryParse" parts saying, "No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments" and when I try to assign a letter grade based on the value of the average. There it says "The name 'A' does not exist in the current context." I don't know what these errors mean so I was wondering if you guys could show me where I've gone wrong. Thanks!

```
namespace Assignment3_attempt_2
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, averageGrade;
            char letterGrade;
            grade1 = double.TryParse(testText1.Text).ToString();
            grade2 = double.TryParse(testText2.Text).ToString();
            grade3 = double.TryParse(testText3.Text).ToString();
            grade4 = double.TryParse(testText4.Text).ToString();
            averageGrade = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4) / 4;
            if (100 >= averageGrade && averageGrade>= 90)
                letterGrade = A;
            if (89 >= averageGrade && averageGrade >= 80)
                letterGrade = B;
            if (79 >= averageGrade && averageGrade >= 70)
                letterGrade = C;
            if (69 >= averageGrade && averageGrade >= 60)
                letterGrade = D;
            else letterGrade = F;
            grade.Text = "The average test grade is " + averageGrade + ".";
            letterGradeLabel.Text = "The letter grade is " + letterGrade + ".";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first error message is pretty clear - you're calling a method and passing only one argument, but the method doesn't have any overload that takes only one argument. Have you tried looking up the definition of [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)? It takes an `out` parameter and returns a `bool`...

Comment: Did you read the TryParse specs?  It returns true or false if it can parse it.  I'm guessing this started as just `double.Parse`, which only takes one parameter.  TryParse uses two.

Comment: For the second error, you have a line: `letterGrade = A;`, yet you haven't defined a variable named `A` anywhere. Perhaps you meant to assign a string? `letterGrade = "A";`

Comment: You've also defined `grade1` as a `double`, yet you're assigning it to a string when you add `.ToString()` at the end of the `double.TryParse` call. You can't do that...you should remove the `ToString()`

Comment: You would have to add `averageGrade.ToString()` when you use that in a string.

Comment: Yeah, I used a line of code I found on this site without truly understanding what it does. So I should just enter parse? Also, I figured out the problem with the second error. I forgot to put single quotes around the letter. This is the post I was looking at to get that line of code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103896/how-can-i-convert-textbox-value-to-double-in-c/35103962

Comment: `TryParse` is better practice, for reasons you won't understand for a bit :). For getting it working, just go with `Parse`

Comment: Did you check the documentation for what arguments `double.tryParse` takes? The error seems pretty straightforward to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TryParse` takes *two* arguments, the string to parse and the variable to stuff it in:

```
double result;
if (double.TryParse("1.0", out result))
{
}
```

It also returns a `bool` so you can use it in an if statement like my sample, instead of throwing when parsing fails. If you want it to throw, `Parse` only takes one argument (and returns the numeric type).

Furthermore, your code takes the `bool` result (`double` if you used `Parse`) then converts it back to a string (`ToString`) then tries to assign *that* to a `double`. The `ToString` definitely shouldn't be there.

Finally a line like:

```
letterGrade = A;
```

Tries to assign `letterGrade` to the *variable* `A`, which doesn't exist (hence the error). If you want to assign to a character literal, you have to surround it in single quotes:

```
letterGrade = 'A';
```